# WS2811 in a 3x3 array not responding to inputs

Tags: c++, fpga

I have a 3x3 array of WS2811 that I am trying to program to activate when you push a button. However, I cannot get it to respond to be 0'd out. Does anyone have any experience working with this hardware and can give some advice on how to make these things work better? I can also provide the code for light_matrix.wr_pix() if that is necessary. Here is my code:

```
/**********************************************************************
 file: main_ws2812_basic.cpp - basic ws2812 test

 Copyright (C) 2018 p. chu

 This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 (at your option) any later version.

 This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 GNU General Public License for more details.

 You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 along with this program.  If not, see <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 **********************************************************************/
/*****************************************************************//**
 * @note neo8 is an 8-led strip
 * @note ws2812 is very bright (25% power is enough)
 * @note ws2812 specifies 5-V control signal
 ********************************************************************/

#include "de10_baseline.h"
#include "ws2812_core.h"
Ws2812Core light_matrix(get_slot_addr(BRIDGE_BASE,14),3,3);
int main() {

   // rgb values of a rain bow (red, orange, yellow, ..., purple)
   const int rainbow[] = { 0xff0000, 0xc04000, 0x808000, 0x00ff00,
                           0x008080, 0x0000ff, 0x4000c0, 0x800080 };
 //  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
 //     }

   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;

   for(i = 0; i<3; i++){
       for(j=0; j<3; j++){
           light_matrix.wr_pix(i,j,0x000000);
       }
   }
   while (1) {

          light_matrix.wr_pix(0,0,0x000000); //green
          light_matrix.wr_pix(0,1,0x000000); //green
          light_matrix.wr_pix(0,2,0x000000); //green
          light_matrix.wr_pix(1,0,0x000000); //blue
          light_matrix.wr_pix(1,1,0x000000); //blue
          light_matrix.wr_pix(1,2,0x000000); //blue
          light_matrix.wr_pix(2,0,0x000000); //green
          light_matrix.wr_pix(2,1,0x000000); //green
          light_matrix.wr_pix(2,2,0x000000); //green

      // 8 shades of blue

    //  neopixel.set_brightness(0.5);

//      //int blue = 0x000007;
//
//      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
//         blue = blue + 31;
//         neopixel.wr_pix(i, 0, blue);
//      }
//
//      sleep_ms(3000);
//      // brightness control (increasing exponentially to 25%)
//      // 100^(1/1000)= 1.0233; i.e., 1.0233^1000 = 100
//      double b = 0.0025;
//      for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++) {
//         b = b * 1.0046;
//         neopixel.set_brightness(b);
//         // set rainbow color
//         for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
//            neopixel.wr_pix(i, 0, rainbow[0]);
//         }
//         sleep_ms(5);
//      }
//      sleep_ms(3000);
//      // animation
//      for (int n = 0; n < 160; n++) {
//         for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
//            int k = (i + n) % 8;
//            neopixel.wr_pix(i, 0, rainbow[0]);
//            sleep_ms(10);
//         }
//      }
     // sleep_ms(2000);
   }//while
}//main
```

Comment: You may have better luck on [electronics.SE] since users on this site may not be familiar with the WS2811 and its associated signalling protocol, libraries, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I will try asking over there.